# Insert NULL with swift + FMDB

Tags: sqlite, swift, null, fmdb

How do I insert NULL into a column with swift

```
let myNullableValue: Double? = nil
fmdb.executeUpdate(
  "INSERT INTO myTable(myNullableColumn) SELECT :myNullableValue"
  , withParameterDictionary: [ "myNullableValue": myNullableValue ])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the FMDB source code at
https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/blob/master/src/fmdb/FMDatabase.m

```
- (void)bindObject:(id)obj toColumn:(int)idx inStatement:(sqlite3_stmt*)pStmt {

    if ((!obj) || ((NSNull *)obj == [NSNull null])) {
        sqlite3_bind_null(pStmt, idx);
    }
    // ...
```

one can conclude that a `NSNull` value is inserted as a SQLite `NULL`,
i.e. the parameter dictionary should be

```
[ "myNullableValue": NSNull() ]
```